# How to copy and render a React element without manually rebuilding it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a very simple drag/drop component, and I thought simply building an array via the `onDrop` event by simply adding the `event.target` to it would suffice, but it seems React doesn't like this. It gives me the error "Objects are not valid as a React child" when rendering, and if I try to clone the elements before adding to the array, I get "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined".

I've searched around, and pretty much the only suggestion I keep seeing for similar questions is to basically reconstruct the elements with whatever props used originally. This is all fine if the element type/props/etc is known and always the same, but what if it isn't? Is there a more flexible solution to copy elements where you might not know how it was originally constructed?

Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function Draggable(props) {
  return <div draggable={true} onDragStart={props.onDragStart}>{props.children}</div>
}

function Droppable(props) {
  return <div onDragOver={props.onDragOver} onDrop={props.onDrop} className="droppable">{props.children}</div>
}

export default function App() {
  const [draggedElement, setDraggedElement] = React.useState(null)
  const [droppedElements, setDroppedElements] = React.useState([])

  function onDragStart(e) {
    setDraggedElement(e.target);
  }

  function onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function onDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDroppedElements([...droppedElements, React.cloneElement(draggedElement, {key: 'test'})]);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Draggable onDragStart={onDragStart}>draggable</Draggable>
      <Droppable onDragOver={onDragOver} onDrop={onDrop}>{droppedElements}</Droppable>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: You are cloning a target element of classic js API. Which is an object, use refs and get a ref to the Dom element eventually

Comment: @quirimmo I've tried using refs instead, but I'm still getting the same errors. Could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.dataTransfer.setData() and e.dataTransfer.getData() to better transfer data. Here's an example of a project I did with draggable card components:

```
const dragStart = e => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        console.log("in dragStart");
        const target = e.target;

        e.dataTransfer.setData('card_id', target.id);
```

```
const drop = e => {
        console.log("Here in first drop function");
        e.preventDefault();
        const card_id = e.dataTransfer.getData('card_id');
        const card = document.getElementById(card_id);
```

And then to drop the card onto something, within the drop function, you can use e.target.append() to drop the data you get from the e.dataTransfer.getData element onto whatever the e.target is.

```
e.target.appendChild(card);
```

so in this case the 'card' in the e.target.appendChild(card) is simply the data that was set in the dragStart function using the e.dataTransfer.setData().
If that makes sense.